# Create SQL script from file having table names as first column and fields as second column

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file containing two columns separated by a space:

```bash
Foo Param1
Foo Param2
Foo Param3
Foo Param4
Foo Param5
Bar Stuff1
Bar Stuff2
Bar Param3
Bar Stuff4
etc
```

The first column is a group name, the second a unique attribute within that group (it may be that an attribute name occurs in two different groups but that's perfectly normal).

From this file, I wish I can create an SQL file like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Param1 text,
   Param2 text,
   Param3 text,
   Param4 text,
   Param5 text
);
CREATE TABLE "Bar" (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Stuff1 text,
   Stuff2 text,
   Param3 text,
   Stuff4 text
);
```

The table name coming from the first column of the file and the second column being used as the fields to create.

What I've tried so far, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14916826/awk-unix-group-by) thread, is something like that:

```bash
awk -F ' ' 'BEGIN{IFS=","}NR>1{arr[$1]++}END{for (a in arr) print "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " a " (" ${arr[*]} " )"}' file.txt
```

But it's obviously not working.

Is there a simple way to achieve that in bash / Ubuntu 22.04?

---

**For the background**: I've extracted images metadata using [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) and I'd like to feed a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) database with one table per [group](https://exiftool.org/#groups) of level 0 with all tags found as attributes.

So the first column in the text file corresponds to the group name, e.g. `EXIF`, `XMP`, or `ICC_Profile`, and for example for the `EXIF` group, the second column has values such as `Artist`, `ColorSpace`, `FNumber` etc.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Are the group names in the first column grouped or can there be rows with `Foo` again after rows with `Bar`?

Comment: @Cyrus the file is sorted by groups, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Do not do it. It is a very bad design pattern. If your source data file would have a new pair of "group-value" or lose it - are you going to rebuild a table for this group? How many groups do you have? Are you sure it is a small constant? How are you suppose to parametrize table names?

Just create a table which follows the data you already have:

```
create table data (
   group text,
   flag text,
   comment text,
   primary key(group, flag)
);
```

Read about EAV database pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, I've just updated the main post. These are naturally nice questions but the moment it's a 'one shot' on a fixed number of input images on which I extract metadata and I wasn't able to find an open source tool for populating a PostgreSQL database from this data.

Comment: @s.k Even with additions to the question the answer remain the same - Do no do multiple tables - that is a very-very-very bad idea.

Comment: yeah but on the other hand it's a very bad idea to have a unique table with more than 1000 fields in a database...

Comment: @s.k where did I suggest a thousand fields??? The table structure, I showed, covers all needs. Read about EAV data model. It is just three fields - id of the object, parameter of the object, and value of the parameter. That is it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The formatting isn't perfectly what you want but I believe PostgreSQL should be quite happy with it

```
awk '
    # continuation lines separated by comma
    $1 == table { print "," }

    # new table needs preamble
    $1 != table {
        # may need to finish previous definition
        if(table > "") { print ");" }

        # preamble
        table=$1;
        printf "create table \"%s\" (\n", table
        print "id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"
    }

    # field
    { printf "%s text\n", $2 }

    # close final table
    END { print ");" }
' datafile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != prev {
    printf "%sCREATE TABLE \"%s\" (\n   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY", end, $1
    end = "\n);\n"
    prev = $1
}
{ printf ",\n   %s text", $2 }
END { printf "%s", end }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
CREATE TABLE "Foo" (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Param1 text,
   Param2 text,
   Param3 text,
   Param4 text,
   Param5 text
);
CREATE TABLE "Bar" (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   Stuff1 text,
   Stuff2 text,
   Param3 text,
   Stuff4 text
);
```